# Why do so many good programmers waste their time on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, answers, behavior

I get depressed when I see so many good programmers answering others' easily-googleable answers, and writing code for them.

I mean, why do you guys do that? How do good programmers have this much time? You must have a job? Or not? Is it hard to get a job as a programmer?

Instead of answering people's questions on Stack Overflow, they can make a website for someone else as a freelancer and earn money.

I am really worried about my future as a programmer.

Comment: Gotta do something on the 2nd monitor whilst watching the cli terminal after typing *"php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile"* for the 800th time \*sighs\* (granted, generally I alias `php bin/magento` to `mage` to save a few keystrokes)

Comment: One big point to remember is that two people can do the same google search and get completely different results.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: It could be a way to improve english skills for non natives speakers, while helping people.

Comment: I don't understand how this [discussion] question got closed as opinion based. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 127):

I see it two ways:

1. I am reinforcing my knowledge of software engineering by answering questions, and in particular, aiming to learn more than what I already know.
2. I am establishing a reputation for myself which I can refer any potential employer to, to showcase what I'm knowledgeable in.

Y'see, I never did internships in college, so this was the next best thing for me.  I've leveraged Stack Overflow to great success in my job searches*, and I feel like the time I put into this site has paid off for me.

Now I get what you're saying; there's a lot of people [painting the bikeshed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality#Examples), and *lordy*, am I ever experiencing that with a recent question of mine, but in frankness, that's really up to the individual contributor, and there's not a lot we can do about that.  If an individual wants to spend the better part of their days answering stupid easy questions, they're more than entitled to do so, but I would hope that any future employer would be able to call them out on their actual skill level.  Or, it could just be their hobby, and I don't see much rationale to take that away from them.

But above all, I answer questions here still because I rather enjoy it.  I tutor others in my spare time, and having the ability to provide some kind of knowledge to someone else actually makes me quite happy.  I certainly hope the kinds of questions I'm answering aren't all that easily Googleable - and they may have been in the past but I believe I've broken that habit now - but I also like to think that the answers I leave here have actually taught someone something.

<sup>*: Ironically, 0 for 4 with Stack Overflow Jobs...</sup>

Comment: Couldn't agree more, it feels good to help people, and I also enjoy answering questions that are outside of the technology stack of my current job at the moment, but that peak my interest. Since you also learn by doing, it also helps answering topics that are in my jobs technology stack, but expand my own knowledge at the same time

Comment: I'm just here to edit things, so it infuriates me when I can't change "peak" in that comment to "pique".  :-)

Comment: @Icepickle Pique not peak :P

Comment: @CodyGray thx, for non-native English speakers, it also improves my language skills ;) Another reason for being active on SO :)

Comment: ***I never did internships in college, so this was the next best thing for me.*** You know what I'm thinking now? Explicitly writing something like this in my resume: _Stackoverflow internship_ "My Top questions are blah, my top answers are blah, and I also contribute in such and such way" I mean for a person who isn't at the senior level it makes total sense

Comment: @CodyGray you actually can edit it now, right? :-)

Comment: @Honey it's considered volunteer work, not only answering /asking questions but also review other people's content, comments, discussing in Meta, ...

Comment: I can, @Don'tPanic, but it would ruin the joke. These are hard times, indeed.

Answer (score 115):

> I get depressed when I see so many good programmers answering other's easily googlable answers, and writing code for them.

You may think they're easily Google-able, but that isn't often the case.  A common problem when getting started is knowing what to look for.  Without a vocabulary around building software, it's hard to know how to get started.

For instance, I'm pretty sure it wasn't until I was learning my second or third programming language until I first heard the word "concatenate".  Now if I want to learn a new language, I know to search for, "[some language] Concatenate Operator".  As someone new to programming though, they're likely to search for something like, "put the text on the screen with other text in [some language]", which of course is going to yield completely useless results.

Another common problem is understanding the layers and how pieces go together.  After you've built a few things, you begin to understand common patterns in architecture and can know roughly how you want to build something before you even know the language or framework you're about to work with.  Someone new has to learn all of this at the same time, so they often confuse things.  (Just look at how many web dev questions there are around people trying to figure out why their PHP code can't be used client-side to handle button clicks.)  When you come across a question that seems high level, a proper answer is to explain the levels in things to allow them to get started and ask more specific questions.

Finally, new folks often don't know how to ask questions.  Building applications is all about figuring things out... and if you can't work through a problem, you're not going to be a good developer.  Asking the correct questions (whether of yourself, or of others) is part of working through a problem.  If you come across a particularly bad question, by all means vote to close it but *add an explanation as to why* so that they have some recourse.

> I mean, why do you guys do that?

I won't speak for others, but my primary reason for helping new people is that my ~3 minutes of effort can save them a day or more depending on the circumstances.  When I was learning to code, I had *nobody* around me to help.  I had no internet access.  All I had were a couple of outdated generic books from the library.  If I had access to resources like StackOverflow back then, I would have no doubt been much better off.

It is important for more experienced folks to help boost the community.  This is a community after all, and those we help will no doubt be those who will be working on our teams in the coming years.  We are all part of a continuum of folks... some are retiring, others are starting.  If we don't invest time into the new generations, what will happen?

> How do good programmers have this much time? You must be having a job? Or not? Is it hard to get a job for programmers?

First off, it doesn't take that much time to help someone.  What I do is when I find an answer on Stack Overflow, I go and answer at least 2 or 3 questions.  Often times, I'm already out-of-the-zone because I'm stuck on a problem, so spending <10 minutes on this isn't going to hurt much.  It's a good use of time... sort of like investing in the community that helps me out as well.

I have a very busy day job, and I also have a mountain of side work to do that I get to when I can.  But it's not just about clock-on-the-wall time.  You make it sound like if I had a few more seconds in the day, I could type more or something.  Sorry, but unless you're regurgitating the same stuff over and over again, your creative hours are far more important... and you'll find that you only get a couple of those hours a day anyway.

> Instead of answering people's question on Stack Overflow, they can make a website for someone else as a freelancer and earn $$.

I find your viewpoint incredibly selfish... but let's go with it.  You shouldn't discount the opportunities you get by participating in a community like Stack Overflow.  **Every** job (day job or otherwise) I've had in the last 6 years was due to my participation on Stack Overflow.  I once got a job because I answered a basic PHP question in a well-explained way for the CEO of a company.  I had no idea he was some CEO, and frankly I wouldn't have cared anyway.  But, he liked my answer and had his developer recruiters follow up with me.  My current day job, the company was looking for a specific combination of skills, and my name came up for that combination and my answers were acceptable.  For my own side business, I mostly do work in a specific area that interests me a great deal.  I've made it a point to answer every single question in this domain on Stack Overflow.  (Usually, I have the best answer.  If I don't know the answer... I really should, so I work to figure it out and then I write a good answer.)  This has worked out very well for me, as folks with larger needs that don't fit in a Stack Overflow question will contact me directly.  If I think what they're asking *could* go on Stack Overflow, I ask them to post there and I answer there... so the whole community can benefit.  If they're not really looking to implement everything themselves, then they hire me to do it.

> I am really worried about my future as a programmer.

Given your attitude, I'd be worried about your future in any profession.  Sounds like you don't really care about the long-term in your line of work.  I hope my post helps you reconsider your position.

Comment: Curious, can you share the link to the answer the CEO liked?

Comment: Old post, but I doubt that OP worrying about his future means he doesn't care about the long term in his work. If anything, it says the *opposite*. He was wondering whether the glut of skilled developers working for free on SO means that there isn't enough paid demand for developers. Luckily that isn't the case, but it's a reasonable thing to wonder about before devoting lots of study to a field.

Answer (score 27):

While I'd agree that earning enough money is important and a pretty key motivator for any programmer, if you happen to have a job that pays *just* enough for you to not have to worry about it much, your perspective on what's worth time can change a bit.

I had a series of pretty not-so-nice jobs during the time that I joined SO, but they always paid just enough that I didn't have to worry about money too often. I had about an hour to kill every day that would have otherwise gone to total waste (probably filling a pool of self-pity).

This is why I started answering questions that I thought looked good, even though others thought many were near duplicates, a bit too basic, or even a bit too narrow (back then, localized):

#### I'm self-taught and wanted peer validation

I wasn't having a confidence crisis or anything, but having my answers peer-reviewed was something new and very satisfying to me when it went well. I kinda got hooked on getting some confirmation that I did have at least some competence and idea of what I was doing.

#### I could give more thorough answers than what existed

I thought good answers should wrap up with an optional exercise for the reader, explain the code presented, provide links and phrases folks could use to get deeper into certain topics covered, or just otherwise take advantage of any reasonable opportunity to be more verbose.

*Or, in short, I wanted Stack Overflow's answers to **be** the ones that you found when you Googled, and I wanted them to be like a page out of a programming book that didn't suck.*

#### I really wanted the better, autonomous features that rep unlocked

I learn systems quickly and I was frustrated with not being able to do more as I saw it. I would rather have just *edited* some additional paragraphs into the top voted answer than write another more verbose (this was a bit before we had a bunch of conversations regarding how substantive an edit could be before it really changed the voice of a post).

And yeah, sure, rep was nice to show off a bit as the site began to be more popular with developers, but I found the actual *privileges* to be more brag-worthy in IRC. Answers that anyone could easily review tended to earn more rep, which got me closer to 10k faster.

So while this is written from the perspective of a bit of an antique that now hangs on a wall, many of the motivators remain relevant. I just thought I'd drop 'em in to bring / keep that perspective.

Comment: This is basically how I started here.  I had some free time, I like to help others, and SO had always helped me in my self teaching before, so I decided to contribute.  That first up vote(validation) was all that I needed to keep going.

Comment: @Nathan that's how it starts - that subtle gateway upvote... Soon, you just want one more upvote, then upvotes just aren't enough, so you try badges, bronze is pointless and at first silver is good, but then, soon you want gold badges because no matter how many silver badges you gain, it's just not as satisfying anymore... :p

Answer (score 26):

One thing that hasn't been touched upon much here:

Self improvement. A very efficient and easy way to pick up a technology or programming language in some capacity (to "get started" so to speak) is to pick easy questions from that technology and research answers for them. It's as much as a self learning experience as it is helping others.

Comment: 100% Even if somebody "scoops" you and posts the answer before you figure it out, you've still learned something.

Comment: Absolutely. Just yesterday I learned how `postMessage` works in Javascript by answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44770308/2288578). Before that I had no idea `postMessage` even existed, let alone the fact that you can open child windows. By using my previous experience in JS (and programming in general) and some quick googling, I was able to get a solid understanding of `postMessage` and provide a complete and correct answer.

Answer (score 22):

I don't know if I'd call myself a "good programmer," although I do think I'm better than bad, but I mainly just answer questions here because I'm bored. I also comment on, vote on, edit, and/or close questions because I'm bored, and occasionally I do some review because I'm bored. Sure, I like the general idea of supporting a useful resource, and the general idea of helping people, even though I don't actually like most of them that much, but mainly it's just because I'm bored. I try to contribute positively while I'm at it because I'm not a jerk, but really any possible benefits of my contributions are just side effects of the boredom alleviation.

It's pretty basic, but I decided to add it as an answer rather than a comment, because with as many people as there are here, surely it's not just me, and I'm a little surprised no one else mentioned it directly. If this gets me some downvotes because I'm selfish, I guess I deserve that, but I'm just being honest.

Comment: Not sure why doing something that helps others is selfish, even if done while bored...  +1

Comment: @Brad I think it's definitely possible for helpful behavior to be motivated by selfishness in some cases. Whether or not the motivation is relevant in your judgement of the value of the behavior just depends on your view of ethics. In my case, I agree with you (or I wouldn't be doing it), but I can see how it would matter to some people.

Answer (score 14):

I do it for fun, and because helping people out and saving them potentially large amounts of time is satisfying. Plus in helping them I get to steer them in the right direction and ensure that in future they are armed with the correct vocabulary and a solid understanding of the subject matter (which also helps ensure they can google their questions more easily).

...and of course I remember what it was like being new at everything, where things that seemed blatantly obvious the experienced programmers were a dark and mysterious world to me, and finding that one tiny piece of information that everyone seemed to know but no one would tell me was a herculean task.

Comment: There's also the notion of "paying it forward". I often have to move between languages, frameworks, technologies, whatever. So I always have questions, and solve many by viewing other's questions on SO. I try to make a point to answer as many questions as have been answered for me . If SO solved an issue for me, I try to solve someone else's. Good karma and all that.

Comment: @railsdog Definitely. Other people have repeatedly put in significant time and effort to solve my problems, so it only seems right that I should put some of my time into solving other people's problems.

Comment: I like this answer; in conjunction with another answer ("You may think they're easily Google-able, but that isn't often the case."), if it's something simple that people just don't know the terminology for, the answer can just be something they CAN Google.  I do skip over what looks like homework questions.  The other thing is that some people are just hobbyists that don't need to study some esoteric programming paradigm in depth just to get their little project working.

Comment: Interesting; do you have an easier time "finding that one tiny piece of information that everyone seemed to know but no one would tell me" on SO? Those are the things that I still seem to find elsewhere: connecting the dots between two blog posts, a mailing list, and an offhand comment in some forum.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I too tend to find the answer elsewhere, however when I'm truly stuck and just cannot find what I want, I leave the computer for a few hours (or sleep on it) then come back when the information I absorbed previously has settled in my mind and from there I can construct a sensible question on SO. Usually that question uses a heap of incorrect terminology and has very flawed logic, but in my experience the answers have always set me on the right path and straightened out the mess of information in my mind. Before SO I tended to just give up because I didn't know what else to do.

Answer (score 9):

> I get depressed when I see so many good programmers answering other's easily googlable answers, and writing code for them.

Most of the time these Google search results take you to Stack Overflow only. Answers written by many such programmers, could be the only learning materials for some self learning kids.

I never used to be so active on the Stack Overflow answering section. And only today I realized that I waste so much time on social media and if I could stop that and share what I know, it could help someone.

Just after 18 hours, I learned quite a few things for myself. So I would say it's definitely good to answer some questions on daily basis. Just try to avoid copy pasting the same answer on different questions. I don't think solving different kinds of questions as a waste of time.

Comment: Yes, it is far better spend than on gaming, watching tv, or even YouTube (depends). See also *[Here Comes Everybody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_Comes_Everybody)*.

Answer (score 8):

I've known employers to look at SO profiles to cross-check applicants. A decent amount of rep and a list of qualified answers to questions can be a good indicator of someones abilities, that can shine beyond a regular CV and portfolio. So there can be a level of self serving behaviour to it, whether it's a conscious decision or not depending on person-to-person.

Personally however, I feel the community on SO represents the general mindset that makes developers who they are - there's a natural desire to acquire and share knowledge. The software ecosystem we live in today wouldn't really be the same if we lived in a walled-off, pay-only learning environment.

Answer (score 3):

Let me preface that I use Stack Overflow and its contributions like oxygen. It's a trusted source of solutions and well moderated opinions. My answer is about why people spend so much time and energy to **CONTRIBUTE**:

In my opinion, it's because Stack Overflow's huge success relies on simple human principles: the need/desire for validation and appreciation. Most responses to this gravitate towards long term self-building goals (career, resumes) and global/selfless benefits (community improvement) - these are 100% legit, but they are the *public* reasons. For most programmers, Stack Overflow is mostly a form of procrasturbation, especially when feeling uninspired to focus on real/personal projects and endeavors. Let's face it, a 2-year project you're working on will see little public and family validation. In fact you might face criticism for spending so much energy that others want, with a decent possibility for obscurity and/or failure. But answer some n00b asking how to sort an array? BOOM! You get an accepted answer, some badges, or total strangers saying "you really helped make my life easier".

It's why otherwise talented people post pictures of their dogs and butts on Instagram, rather than choosing to vanish into the darkness of their studio for 6 lonely and grueling months to actually create something.

But we're only human, and you can't create on empty. That's why I think Stack Overflow is amazing, even in that selfish way. You gotta keep that self-worth tank filled somehow.

Comment: I think there's really some truth here, but for most people I doubt it's the _only_ reason they contribute. I think people contribute for a mix of reasons, and this can be a part of it to varying degrees. Many wouldn't want to admit that it's even part of their motivation, but everybody loves their upvotes.

Comment: There is also the memory of the era of horrible, horrible forums. And [the hyphen site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange). And the glorious [Usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) days (before it was [destroyed by AOL overnight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September)).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you derived value from SO? Ignoring the arguments it's increasingly commercialized post-Joel as CEO, I'd say most of us have gotten a *ton* of value from SO. Finding answers to coding questions is *sooooo* much easier than it was 20 years ago.

How can you derive so much value without giving some back? Everyone benefits by paying it forward a bit.

Here's a little snippet from a blog entry of mine titled, [My work here is done, Stack Overflow](https://myfreakinname.blogspot.com/2015/11/my-work-here-is-done-stackoverflow.html):

> I'll try not to get too verklempt, but I finally hit my informal goal for StackOverflow: I received the second JSLint badge SO's awarded.
>
> It used to be difficult to program without googling answers to what were sometimes pretty straightforward questions -- it was more efficient -- and smarter -- to "borrow" and improve on something that'd already been through the crucible than coding "from scratch". Now, it's even more difficult to code without leaning heavily on StackOverflow.
>
> It should also be hard to receive that much value without giving something back. Admittedly, I'm nowhere near as "giving" as one of my old coworkers, who is creeping up on 80,000 StackOverflow points [now 112k] as I blog. But you shouldn't feel good about benefiting from StackOverflow without finding some means of giving back.
>
> For me, giving back was sitting on the JSLint tag. We started using JSLint at a company I worked with a while back, and I think I was one of our better JavaScript guys (ie, Whitaker, above, was pretty busy, so I guess I was second), so I got stuck with implementing JSLint as a company-wide blocking check-in test for TFS... slowly forcing us to JSLint our legacy code (though with exceptions for third-party libraries) as we edited files...
>
> ...
>
> Regardless, like [Jim Morris pitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Morris#Baseball_career), the unofficial work meant I became pretty good at understanding JSLint. More importantly, JSLint was (and is!) a manageable tag on StackOverflow... It was a small pond, but active enough that you could actually contribute.

Blah blah blah, TL;DR -- So I gave back.

And, as others say, you can still send anyone interested in working with you to the site to see not only are you good at what you do, and good at *explaining* what you do, but that *people appreciate how you do both*.

That's harder for most of us to get from a simple blog entry or Udemy video.

Comment: [Stack Overflow, not StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section) - in your blog post.

Comment: But macOS looks so much cooler. ;)